# How to prevent a particular terminal (e.g. /dev/tty1) from writing the cursor to framebuffer (e.g. /dev/fb0)

Tags: tty, framebuffer, cursor

I'm running Raspbian Buster with no Xserver but attached to a television.  I have a script that writes an image to the framebuffer from a timed systemd service.

The problem is /dev/tty1 is writing its blinking cursor (with black character sized box) that appears over the image.  I would like to prevent /dev/tty1 from writing to the framebuffer in a safe manner.  I suppose if I lose SSH access I would need to use /dev/tty1 to recover machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the cursor invisible with the `civis` terminfo escape:

```
tput civis > /dev/tty1
```

`tput cnorm` to restore it.

> I suppose if I lose SSH access I would need to use `/dev/tty1` to recover machine.

Doesn't that device have any serial port? That's a bit more robust than a framebuffer console.

Comment: With `sudo tput civis > /dev/tty1` I'm getting "/dev/tty1: Permission denied".  What do I do with a serial port?  I can just connect a USB keyboard to connect to tty1 no?

Comment: That will not open `/dev/tty1` as root. I'm not using sudo (ever!), but try `sudo sh -c 'tput civis > /dev/tty1'`.

Comment: Great it worked.  Why did I need "sh -c"?

Comment: In your command, it was the current shell (running as as regular user) tha opened `/dev/tty1`, not the command run under `sudo`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the case that didn't work (`sudo tput civis > /dev/tty1`) I'm only a sudoer not the root user.  And to for this command you need to be root user to gain privilege?

Comment: You simply need to have write permissions to `/dev/tty1`. Usually only the root and users from the `tty` group have permissions, and the user logged in in that terminal. It doesn't matter if the user is a sudoer or not.

Comment: And a systemd service will be root (not a sudoer) and will have access to /dev/tty1?

Comment: Can you reflect `sudo sh -c 'tput civis > /dev/tty1' in your answer since the question is specifically for someone not logged into /dev/tty1.  Thanks for you help.